# Ultra Stable Current Source At Up To 2 A

Tags: current, source, stable

Can anyone suggest circuit(s) that can produce a very stable current source, preferably trimmable to close to 1 or 2 amps?  Stability is the main requirement,  all help is greatly appreciated. I have a good 6.5 digit dmm 0.005%  so can use that to check resistors, voltages etc and have a few 0.01% resistors 200/10/20/10 ohms and a 0.1% 0.1ohm unit all 4 wire.  Thanks.

Comment: Please don't shout.

Comment: What RMS noise will you tolerate? what is the bandwidth of the regulatory loop? 1 Hertz? 10,000Hz? is any overshoot allowed, upon changes to the current?

Comment: What is ultra-stable to you, in engineering units?  My "ultra-stable" might be your "ultra-noisy", and visa-versa.

Comment: What headroom? How about 20 volts total, with 10 volts for the sensing resistor and 10 volts for the load? In that case, 10 microVolts RMS feedback-loop random noise would be about 2ppm (10uVrms/5Vrms). In 10,000Hz bandwidth, that allows 100 nanoVolts/rtHz feedback-loop noise which should be easy, except there needs to be a low-noise Vref and a low-noise DAC to set the desired current.

Comment: Stable over temperature, or time, or load, or do you mean low noise? The resistors that you mentioned, are these available for the design, or are these what you want to measure?

Comment: 6.5 digits is not a spec.  Do not ask for any design suggestions nor start any design until you define accuracy,  input + output V range, load slew rate, temperature rise etc

Answer (score 3):

The LT3080 is a good LDO with 1A of current and under 30uV of noise, two of them can be paralleled to get 2A.

[image]

Or you can use two in series to get a supply with CC/CV capability (if you only want Constant Current variability then use the first half of the circuit):
[image]

The offset voltage is very stable over temperature:

[image]

Source: https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt3080.html#product-documentation

If the LT3080 doesn't work, then try the [LT3045](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt3045.html) which has less current output but better noise and stability specs.